# How to disable the new feature of Visual Studio 2022 that resembles GitHub Autopilot?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

It seems that Visual Studio 2022 has a new feature that resembles GitHub Autopilot.

This is an image related to this feature:

[image]

This feature is very very annoying (slow and unpredictable and interfering with your typing speed). Thus I searched to see how can I disable it. But I can't find anything.

So, how can I disable this?

Answer (score 3):

The new Intellicode in Visual Studio was pretty annoying for me as well, and I was able to follow the steps in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007337/how-to-disable-new-ai-based-intellicode-in-vs-2022) to disable it completely.

However, if you just want to disable the specific prompt, you can press `esc` and dismiss the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Some extensions can cause a typing delay, for example Rainbow Braces. It can cause a lag of few secs trying to type, usually on large files > 5000 lines. After disabling the typing comes to normal.