# Disable new "Diff view" IntelliCode suggestions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

After updating Visual Studio 2022 there seem to be a new style of IntelliCode that Peter Groenewegen referees to on [twitter](https://twitter.com/pgroene/status/1590806657608843264?cxt=HHwWgIDQ0cCO15MsAAAA).
I find it very intrusive and want to get rid of it but cant seem to find a setting.
Am I missing something or is it one more of the new bloats in VS that you can't get rid of unless you kill the whole feature?

I'm really trying to like intelicode but it is slow and often suggest garbage so it is hard for me to like it. And now this.
VS staring to look like a three year old kid with crayons went over it and I would like to tone it down but not kill the features unless there is absolutely no other way.

Does anyone know if there is a setting somewhere?

Update: The settings (or it is just my settings) has ben largely removed so I don't have a lot of options to try.
Images of all my settings
[image: Intelicode general settings]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007337/how-to-disable-new-ai-based-intellicode-in-vs-2022 I haven't personally disabled it, but I do find the new format with red coloring much too intrusive.

Comment: Do you still have these settings? Mine have been removed. See the images I added to my post.